# How to save the currently opened tabs (URLs) of Firefox into a text file?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Is there a way to save the currently opened tabs (URLs) of Firefox into a text file?

Comment: Firefox presumably does this already, since it offers to restore your tabs after an update or a crash. I would expect the information is stored as text: search through your filesystem for files containing key words from the URLs in your current tabs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [**URL Lister**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7192) add-on.

> Shows the URLs of all the tabs in a
>   textarea so that it can be copied
>   easily.

[image]

Comment: URL Lister is very handy, thanks for the tip. However, once your list is saved to a file, you might want to open all of them in tabs, i.e. restore the list. For this task, I made a simple Python script called [open_in_tabs.py](http://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/open-urls-in-browser-tabs-simultaneously/). Its usage is very simple: `cat url_list.txt | ./open_in_tabs.py`

Answer (score 0):

I know it to be the case of foldered bookmarks at least, so that would be a roundabout way of doing it. Simply right-click folder, copy, and then paste into a text file or mail. Then it should generate a list of links.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Multiple Tab Handler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4838/) can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is this module, which can format (a bit) the list if you want : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/send-tab-urls/
It saved my day, thanks to its developer !